# Disable optimistic locking in grails domain class

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I am having an issue with the version column. Sometimes the version is 0 and sometime 1. If it's 0 then I can log in but when it's 1, I can't log in.

I tried to turn off the version column. But I can't.

```
static mapping = { 
    version false 
}
```

I found the above solution on internet to turn off version column. But it shows an warning `version can not be applied to (java.lang.boolean)` and version column is still here.

May grails version is 3.2.7 and groovy version is 2.4.7.

Comment: That is the correct format, can you show the full domain class? Also if you are logging in ensure that whatever methods are invoked in that process are in a read only transaction.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```java
static mapping = {
  version(false)
}
```

also drop the version column from your table in database